# How to convert a MySQL database from utf8mb4 to utf8?

Tags: mysql, collation, character-set, type-conversion, utf-8

I would like to convert a MySQL database, which has `utf8mb4` character set and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`collation, to `utf8` and `utf8_unicode_ci`.

How to do that please?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: You are aware that UTF8 uses 3 bytes/character and UTF8mb4 uses 4 bytes/character, right? This means you could lose some characters due to the conversion.

Comment: Why do you want to change the CHARACTER SET?  I ask because there may be a better solution to the underlying question.

Comment: Not only might you lose a 4-byte character, you might lose the rest of the string.

Comment: @dartonw: Thanks. I converted a forum database from latin1 to utf8mb4, using a software. I had two options: utf8 or utf8mb4 (these are the only options to use with the new version of the forum). I chose utf8mb4, but with the converted utf8mb4, I had difficulty to import it to the server using mysqldumper (it either stopped at an internal server error or was stuck at some point). With latin1, it was very fast. Therefore, I think that maybe utf8 is more suitable. But since I did not keep the original latin1 database, my only choice is to convert from utf8 to utf8mb4.

Comment: @RickJames: Thanks for the replies. Please read my above comment.

Comment: Suggest you complain to mysqldumper (about which I know nothing).  utf8 and utf8mb4 are very similar.  Chinese is the main language that really needs utf8mb4 instead of utf8.  Also, some emoticons need utf8mb4.  Plan A: Load the dumper into utf8.  Plan B: Show us the errors, maybe we can figure it out.

Comment: Hi @RickJames. I have tested again, and suprisingly everything went well. Maybe the last time I tried there was a problem with the server (I did many backup/restore operations the other day, so I guess that the limit number of connections was attained or the tmp directory of mysql server was full, or something similar). Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

I just solved the charset problem by using Notepad++.

The problem was that my php version is 4.5.5.1 and the hosting firm's was 3.3.8. Because of that, it could not work with the `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.

To solve the problem open the exported SQL file, search and replace the `utf8mb4` with `utf8`, after that search and replace the `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` with `utf8_general_ci`. Save the file and import it into your database. After that, change the *wp-config.php* charset option to `utf8`, and the magic starts.

Note that it worked in a Hungarian database.

Comment: You should replace the `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` with `utf8_general_ci` first as if you do the first search and replace with `utf8mb4` with `utf8` it will overwrite the first replace and cause `utf8_unicode_520_ci` to be created

Answer (score 1):

Run in PhpMyAdmin:

```
ALTER DATABASE yourdatabasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: This does not change the columns, it only changes the _default_ for newly created tables in _that_ database.